# time.Time#UnmarshalBinary in for-loop does output the same value continuously

Tags: for-loop, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to build a timer-application which for persistence saves the target-t.Time in a binary file, I was able to figure out marshaling but unmarshaling gives me a little problem

I'm able to read the 15bit chunks for each `time.Time` correctly, but when I try to unmarshal them, the function seems to reference the same value each iteration. When I print out `buf` in the loop, the correct bit-values appear, but when I print out the unmarshaled values it's only the first `time.Time`.

Can somebody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong? here is the code for my `readFile` function:

```
func readDat() []time.Time {
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("dat")
    check(err)

    var targets []time.Time
    var buf = make([]byte, 15)
    var bufT time.Time

    for i, o := 0, 0; o < len(f); i++ {
        buf = f[o : o+15]
        bufT.UnmarshalBinary(buf) // pointer? bits in buf sind korrekt
        targets = append(targets, bufT)
        o = o + 16
    }

    return targets
}
```

Comment: You could check the [error returned by [UnmarshalBinary](https://godoc.org/time#Time.UnmarshalBinary) to see if anything is wrong with your data. Maybe declaring `bufT` inside of the loop could also help

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I have changed below in the working example.  But most importantly youneed to check your returned errors.  The problem had to do specifically with offsetting `o` by 16 instead of 15 (the number of bytes per time.Time).

The reason you see the same time on each iteration is because you are only successful in unmarshalling the first time, then you are off by 1, then off by 2, etc, etc so the time won't unmarshal correctly again until you have 15 times in a row.  Since your `bufT` is never updated after the first iteration, and you don't check the error code, the same one is added repeatedly.

```
const timeSize = 15

func readDat() []time.Time {
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("dat")
    check(err)

    var targets []time.Time
    var buf = make([]byte, timeSize)
    var bufT time.Time

    for i := 0; i < len(f); i += timeSize {
        copy(buf, f[i:i+timeSize])
        err := bufT.UnmarshalBinary(buf)
        check(err)
        targets = append(targets, bufT)
    }

    return targets
}
```

Comment: thank you very much? could you give me the particular reason, why you declared timeSize as a constant and not just put the 15 in there? I don't quite from my EE and Informatics studies, and as I read up just now they seem to behave a little differently anyway in go. make seems to accept any integer types. or was it just because it's the naturally the same amount of bits needed. any reason it's not just an integer declared in the function, when I'm not using it anywhere else

Comment: Reason to use a var (or const in this case) is to remove the multiple occurrences of `15` appearing (reducing chance of type).  Why use a const?  So you can't accidentally change it - because it is constant.  In Go, the default type of an untyped numeric constant is a signed int, which is what `15` is.